# Attaching xml file to mimeentity crashes Notes server

Tags: java, xml, email, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

In an Java agent I generate a mail. When I send this only with text then the mail is sent to the recipient. I also want to attach an xml file to the mail. If I attach it my notes server crashes.

I think my code is wrong, this is the part where I want to add the attachment to the mail:

```
         mime = mimeRoot.createChildEntity();
         MIMEHeader hdr = mime.createHeader("Content-Disposition");
         hdr.setHeaderValAndParams("attachment; filename=" + OrderFilePath); 
         Stream stream = session.createStream();
         System.out.println("Open stream");
      //AT THIS IF IT WILL CRASH THE SERVER
         if (stream.open(OrderFilePath, "binary")){
             System.out.println("in eerste if");
             if (stream.getBytes() != 0) {
                 System.out.println("getbytes !0 ");
                   mime.setContentFromBytes(stream, "application/octet-stream",MIMEEntity.ENC_IDENTITY_BINARY);

             }
               else System.out.println
                 (OrderFilePath + "has no content or is not working");
             }
```

Comment: How big is the file?

Comment: not big 10kb approx

Comment: Do you have the NSD file from the server crash?

Comment: Yes I have but they are rather big

Comment: Search for the word "Fatal" in the NSD and look in the stacktrace that immediately follows it. The names of the functions that were invoked in the fatal thread will often give clues. In fact, if you plug a line or two of the stacktrace info into google, it might even bring up an IBM technote describing the error and maybe a solution. Most server crashes, after all, are IBM bugs; except in cases like memory exhaustion or misuse of a Notes C API or third-party native library call, either the JVM or the amgr task should be detecting errors and avoiding crashes.

Answer (score 0):

I have some working LotusScript code that does almost the same, with the exception of two lines:

```
hdr.setHeaderValAndParams("attachment; filename=\\"" + OrderFilePath + "\\"");
```

and

```
mime.setContentFromBytes(stream, "application/octet-stream; name=\\"" + OrderFilePath + "\\"",MIMEEntity.ENC_IDENTITY_BINARY);
```

My LS code, so yo can see for yourself:

```
    ForAll att In attachments
        disposition= "attachment"
        If att.isInLine Then disposition= "inline"
        Set sect = body.createChildEntity()
        Call sect.CreateHeader("Content-Disposition").SetHeaderValAndParams(disposition + {; filename="} & att.attName & {";"} )
        Call sect.CreateHeader("Content-ID").SetHeaderVal( |<| & ListTag(att) & |>| )
        Set stream = session.CreateStream
        If stream.Open(att.attFile) Then
            Call sect.SetContentFromBytes(stream, strContentType & {; name="} & att.attName & {"}, ENC_IDENTITY_BINARY)
            Call stream.Close
        End If
    End Forall
```

*attachments* is a list of *Attachment* objects that contain only the name and the filepath of an attachment; it isn't a full Notes attachment embedded object thing.